# Fixing 'Accelerometer' is not defined no-undef in react

Tags: reactjs

I have this `.js` file in a react project:

```
const acl = new Accelerometer({ frequency: 60 });
let data = {"samples": [], "way": ''}
let idx = 0;

const onAccChange = () => {
    data.push({ "idx": idx, "time": acl.timestamp, "seconds_elapsed": 0, 
                "x": acl.x, "y": acl.y, "z": acl.z });
    idx += 1;
}

const aclAddEventListener = () => {
    acl.addEventListener("reading", onAccChange);
}

const aclRemoveEventListener = () => {
    acl.removeEventListener("reading", onAccChange);
}
```

When I run `npm run build` I get `'Accelerometer' is not defined  no-undef` although this `.js` works perfectly in a non-react project.

> The Accelerometer interface of the Sensor APIs

and is documented [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Accelerometer)

Answer (score 0):

The Accelerometer interface is not defined in React by default. You need to import it from the

> react-native

package. In your case, you can add the following import statement to the top of your file:

```js
import Accelerometer from 'react-native';
```

Once you have imported the Accelerometer interface, you can create a new instance of it as follows:

```js
const acl = new Accelerometer({ frequency: 60 });
```

This will create a new Accelerometer object that will be able to read the acceleration of the device. You can then use the Accelerometer object to get the acceleration data as follows:

```js
const data = acl.getAcceleration();
```

The data object will contain the acceleration data for the device. The data object will have the following properties:

x: The acceleration of the device along the x axis.
y: The acceleration of the device along the y axis.
z: The acceleration of the device along the z axis.
You can then use the data object to do whatever you need to do with the acceleration data. For example, you could use the data to create a motion-controlled game or to track the movement of a user.

Here is a complete example of how to use the Accelerometer interface in React:

```js
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import Accelerometer from 'react-native';

class App extends Component {

  state = {
    data: {}
  };

  componentDidMount() {
    const acl = new Accelerometer({ frequency: 60 });
    acl.addEventListener('reading', (event) => {
      this.setState({
        data: {
          x: event.x,
          y: event.y,
          z: event.z
        }
      });
    });
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <h1>Accelerometer Example</h1>
        <p>The acceleration of the device is:</p>
        <p>X: {this.state.data.x}</p>
        <p>Y: {this.state.data.y}</p>
        <p>Z: {this.state.data.z}</p>
      </div>
    );
  }
}

export default App;
```

This code will create a simple app that displays the acceleration of the device. You can use this code as a starting point to create your own apps that use the Accelerometer interface.